# Does memory leak if we set ItemSource property of a control to null in WPF?

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, wpf-controls

I have a TabControl which havs two TabItems. Each of these two TabItems has a listbox. On the SelectionChanged event handler I am setting ItemSource property of the appropriate ListBox to null and populating the other one with a Collection. Now when I keep on selecting each Tab there is a memory spike. Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure its the listboxes causing the memory spike and not the TabControl it self? TabControls in WPF will only hold the visual tree for the currently selected tab. When you change selected tab, the TabControl build the visual tree for the newly selected tab which can cause memory consumption (+CPU).

Answer (score 1):

Try not emptying the lists when you change tabs, I don't think WPF will attempt to draw the list if it is not being displayed. When I need to make a listbox/ itemscontrol display a collection of objects I do this:

```
//have all the usual usings and
using System.ComponentModel
using System.Collections.ObjectModel
class Bar : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   //make your properties setters call PropertyChanged
}
class Bars : ObservableCollection<Bar>
{
}
```

then set your listbox to have `ItemsSource` as your instance of `Bars` and use a data template to display each `Bar`. This means that you never have to set `ItemsSource` again (becuase `ObservableCollection` will automatically tell the listbox to update when something changes) which I am guessing is where the leak is occuring. By not repetedly changing `ItemsSource` the program will *probably* be more efficient but that is not a guarantee `:)` if you get desperate, Red-Gate do a free [.net reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) so you can have a peek at what your ListBox is actually doing.

Another problem could be that the listbox isn't virtualizing properly but I seem to remember that ListBoxes do virtualize but you will need a second oppinion for that.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it doesn't appear this way but a TabControl is just a normal ItemsControl. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.aspx

Setting the selected Item to a Tab the Visual Tree is completly built from its containing Content.

If you have a freezing Page try to load your data asynchronously in a `Task Factory`.

Also maybe clear your Collection instead of setting it to null :)